# How do I post a message with a video to a Facebook Page using Koala?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, koala

I'm trying to post a video along with a message on a Page with Koala. I'm not referring to the title or caption, but a message just like a normal wall or picture post.

For example, this is how I'm posting a picture:

`page_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(some_page_access_token)`
`page_graph.put_picture(some_picture_url, {message: "hello, world!"}, page_id)`

This works perfectly. I end up with a post on the page's wall with my photo and the message provided.

I'm doing something very similar with videos:

`page_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(some_page_access_token)`
`page_graph.put_video(some_video_url, {message: "hello, world!"}, page_id)`

However, in this case, my video posts, but my message is not posted.

The picture below highlights what I'm trying to achieve.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I just figured this out. Supposed to use `description` instead of `message`.

It should be: `page_graph.put_video(some_video_url, {description: "hello, world!"}, page_id)`